# How to prove the Riemann rearrangement theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\sum a_n$ be a series of real numbers which converges,but not absolutely.Suppose $-\infty \le \alpha \le \beta \le \infty $.Then there exists a rearrangement $\sum a'_n $ with partial sums $s'_n$ such that $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} s'_n=\alpha,\; \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} s'_n=\beta.$$

Comment: Separate the terms into positive and negative groups, sums of these will be $\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively. Starting from any number, you can get near any other number by adding terms from the appropriate group. $\lim a_n = 0$ guarantees these paths get more and more precise and it should be obvious you can reach arbitrary infimum and supremum.